# Why am I getting so many DSL Link Retrains

Tags: connection, modem, noise, dsl

My DSL modem keeps on interrupting my normally speedy internet browsing saying that it has problems connecting. When I open the router statistics I see this:

```
Since Reset | Current 24-Hour Interval | Current 15-Minute Interval | Time Since Last Event

DSL Link Retrains:      59  22  0   0:14:45
DSL Training Errors:    10  5   0   0:16:16
```

I'm not an expert so I'm not sure if the noise listed in the connection details is good or bad:

```
DSL Connection Details
DSL Line (Wire Pair):   Line 1 (inner pair)
Protocol:   G.DMT Annex A
Downstream Rate:    3008 kbps
Upstream Rate:  512 kbps
Channel:    Fast
Current Noise Margin:   19.0 dB (Downstream) 21.0 dB (Upstream)
Current Attenuation:    20.1 dB (Downstream) 9.0 dB (Upstream)
Current Output Power:   0.7 dBm (Downstream) 5.3 dBm (Upstream)
DSLAM Vendor Information:   Country: {0x00} Vendor: {ALCB} Specific: {0x00}
PVC Info:   0/35
```

Should I be worried about line noise, is this a problem with my modem, or is this an issue with my provider? or do I need to provide any more information?

Thanks for your help. This has been very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely explanation is that you have bursts of noise. Your noise margin is still showing as good because it's an average.

The most common cause of bursts of noise on DSL lines is a missing DSL filter. The second most common cause is poor quality house wiring. Unfortunately, most of the other causes are things you can't do anything about.

So first, check for missing DSL filters. *Every* device connected to your line must have one. It's easy to forget about alarm systems, satellite TV receivers, TiVo boxes, and the like. Of course, that includes FAX machines, cordless phone base stations, and so on.

Next, check your interior wiring. If your house is like most houses, you have phone jacks in every room but probably only use one or two of them for a cordless phone system base station and your DSL modem. If possible, identify dead runs and disconnect them.

If this still fails, you can install a "whole house splitter" at the point of entry (where your phone line enters your house). This allows you to use separate interior wiring for the DSL and voice portions of the line.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted above, I can see that your Noise Margain is right where it should be (10b or higher is best).  However, the data speed levels are low.  This is likely the result of whatever is causing the low power output reading.

What we'd need to do, in order to isolate this, is run some tests with our systems.  This will let us see if any 'errors' are generating as a result of a fault in the line.  Also, what was posted above by the other commentor is great advice and the best place to start.

If you're unable to get anywhere with this, go ahead and send your information to us so we can dig deeper.  This link takes you to our support page:

https://promotions.centurylink.com/contact/index.php

Comment: Don't use URL shorteners, please.